# while connecting to MicrosoftSQL server using Django facing django.db.utils.OperationalError:

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-database, django-database-functions

```
drivers available with me
**python shell** 
    '''In [2]: pyodbc.drivers()'''
**Output:**
    **Out[2]: ['SQL Server']**

code in settings.py django:


    **Settings.py in django**

    '''# Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': 'dbname',
            'HOST': 'ansqlserver.database.windows.net',
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': 'Password',

            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'SQL Server',
            }
        }'''





 **ERROR:**
    **Trying to connect to MicrsoftSQL server facing below error**
```

File "C:\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 314, 
        in get_new_connectiontimeout=timeout)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Neither DSNnor SERVER keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initally I have only one driver: 'SQL Server'

later I installed different drivers

Just enter command and see the drivers in your machine 
'''pyodbc.drivers()'''

Output: ['SQL Server',
 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server']

after that I am able to connect to MicrosoftSQL DB without any issues

Answer (score 0):

Check if your database host "ansqlserver.database.windows.net" has permission to allow application server to connect.

Comment: hi rajeev I have permission,  when i  connect when I use pyodbc and python code to connect  it is working fine, but not working in django

Comment: I think there is an issue with Database settings. Try changing "options", use this link for 
[mssql](https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/)

Comment: no rajeev issue is with the drivers initially  I don't have  any drivers other that 'SQL Server'
now installed different drivers this solved the issue, thanks